# Something is wrong with my bash prompt?

Tags: command-line, bash

So when I type with my new bash prompt it goes on for a while, but if the command gets to long it loops around itself and writes over bash prompt. Here is my PS1 :

```
PS1='\e[0;34m\A\e[m | \e[0;31m-\e[m \e[0;32m>>\e[m  '
```

For reference, here are the lines from a standard .bashrc relevant to PS1:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: For reference, here are the lines from a standard `.bashrc` relevant to `PS1`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7576468/. My guess is that you don't have any closing brackets in your `PS1`.

Comment: still nothing. I tried adding brackets but all it did was add random brackets in the text I can see

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the escape sequences in `\[  \]`:

```
PS1='\[\e[0;34m\]\A\[\e[m\] | \[\e[0;31m\]-\[\e[m\] \[\e[0;32m\]>>\[\e[m\]  '
```

This is essentially the same as @user107425's answer but using the `\e` instead of `\033` syntax and with the closing `\[\e[m\]` that resets the color to the default after the end of the prompt.